# when using router-link in vue js page refresh

Tags: vue.js

```
<ul class="main-search-list-defaultlist d-none">
  <li class="auto-suggestion d-flex align-items-center cursor-pointer" v-for="(user, index) in userFromSearch"
    :key="index">
    <router-link class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between w-100" :to="/profile/+user.id"
      @click.native.prevent="cc()">
      <div class="d-flex">
        <div v-if="user.chanel.image">
          <div class="mr-50"><img :src="uesrSearchImage(user.chanel.image)" alt="png" height="50"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="search-data">
          <p class="search-data-title mb-0"></p><small class="text-muted">{{user.name}}</small>
        </div>
      </div><button class="search-data-size mr-50 text-muted">17kb</button>
    </router-link>
  </li>
</ul>
```

this ul appear when user search for another user but when click on the user the page is refresh

Comment: What is the definition of `cc()`?

Comment: cc is a methode only have one line alert() to test